# Computer and mobile tcp communication problems

Tags: tcp

In my project, mobile phone and computer tcp communication is possible on some computers, but some computers are not (these computers can be turned on a few minutes before turning on), what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you tell is not very clearly. I think it's better to get the logs and capture TCP streams by wireshark or tcpdump firstly. It will be great help to analysis the problem and other problems of network.